# iOS not receiving user to user app requests

Tags: ios, facebook, apprequests, facebook-app-requests

I am sending app requests from an iOS native app using Facebook SDK dialog.  I have created a canvas app and set the iTunes ID (using a valid ID from a different app in the store now, since mine is not).  The requests arrive at desktop www site, and show up under "App and Games>Invites from friends".  But, they do not show up on iOS native Facebook app, unless I first do Facebook SSO with my app.  Then, my app bookmark appears in FB, and new requests increment the counter.

How do I get the requests to show up on iOS before my app is installed?  Other peculiar thing that may be related, is I get no activity under "Notifications" on iOS, only the app bookmark.  On desktop, I see the Notifications globe flash with a red badge at first logon, but then the badge goes away and nothing is there, although the requests appear under "Apps and games".  This seems not totally consistent as some people who have tested my app get the expected Notification behavior, but I never do on my own FB account.  Could it be because if added and removed the app repeatedly for testing?

Any clues?

Comment: Is you bundle ID the same in facebook and the app?

Answer (score 0):

My problem seems to have been something fouled up in the Facebook database, probably as a result of my various misfires in early development.  At some point it began working correctly without any changes on my end.